# jQuery ajax if results are empty

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing an ajax lookup using jQuery, which is all going swimmingly. However I want to be able to do something special if the lookup itself is successful but returns an empty result. For example I'm using code like this to do the lookup:

```
jq.ajax({
  url: '/getMatches',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'text=' + jq(this).val(),
  success: function(data) {
    jq.each(data, function(k, v) {
      jq('#results ul').append('<li><a href="' + v.url + '">' + v.title + '</a></li>')
    });
  }
});
```

If there are results it will look like this:

```
<div id="results">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="www.example.com/one">Example one</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.example.com/two">Example two</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.example.com/three">Example three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to do the following if there are no results:

```
<div id="results">
  <p>There are no results</p>
</div>
```

I couldn't see anything in the jQuery docs, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the response data is a JSON array, you can simply check the `length` property:

```
if(!data.length) {
   //no results...
   return;
}

jq.each(data, function(k, v) {
  jq('#results ul').append('<li><a href="' + v.url + '">' + v.title + '</a></li>')
});
```

Comment: Great, works well. By the way, what does triple equals mean? I would have normally used a double equals